# Quectel MC25 Module not giving AT response

Tags: embedded, stm32, at-command, modem, quectel

I'm using the Quectel MC25 Module with an STM32 for a tracking device. The module works well for a few hours, then stops responding to AT commands and gets stuck. How can I fix this issue?

The module should give correct responses of the AT commands before it moves further, for example the response for AT should be "OK". However, the modem gets stuck after a few iterations and stops working.

Comment: Ascertain, whether the modem stops communicating, or your device stops asking and/or properly decoding the answer. Monitor the lines to modem using oscilloscope, LA, or just connecting them to Rx of a listening device such as PC with a terminal program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question adding your findings when doing what wek suggests. You might also want to write a [mre] that simply tries `"AT"` in an endless loop.